# Right way routing urls in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, routes

I want to know what is the right way to do routes in codeigniter.
So far first and second routh work perfect, but when i want to add last one, code doesn't work.

Controller store shows categorys. When i click on one category, let sey mens-were, it show all sub-categorys and so on and on. But last routh doesn't work for me, because second route allready gets called. So there must be some sort of work-around!

```
$route['store/mens-were'] = "store/show_subcategorys";
$route['store/menswear/(:any)'] = "store/show_products_in_subcategory";
$route['store/menswear/mens-jackets/(:any)'] = "store/show_product";
```

Can enybody help?

tnx!

Comment: Reverse the order and it should work.

Comment: can you please provide at least one example?

Comment: Order matters! Routes are processed from top to bottom. Once one works, the rest are ignored.

Comment: Oh i get it now! :) 
TNX

Comment: Feel free to mark @ISuthanBala 's answer as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to place them in the right order. In your case, it should be:

`$route['store/mens-were'] = "store/show_subcategorys";
$route['store/menswear/mens-jackets/(:any)'] = "store/show_product";
$route['store/menswear/(:any)'] = "store/show_products_in_subcategory";`